# Why does the printout does not change between DataFrame to DataFrameGroupBy?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, group-by, data-analysis

Here i have a DataFrame with data of passengers from Titanic. 
I want to group the data based on Age column, yet when I apply the groupby method, the output seems exactly the same. 
The type changes though, from DataFrame to DataFrameGroupBy.

Why don't I see any grouping, then?
Why does the printout not change between DataFrame and DataFrameGroupBy?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


test_titanic = pd.read_csv("https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1166/stuff/titanic.csv")

test_titanic_age = test_titanic.groupby("Age")

print(test_titanic.head())
print(type(test_titanic))

print(test_titanic_age.head())
print(type(test_titanic_age))
```

[My printout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaPce.png)

Comment: you need to provide the snippet of your input dataframe. Also, the code you have used for group-by. otherwise this question is too broad.

Comment: I forgot to, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has grouped the whole dataset by age of passengers. you just don't see it in the way you print it.
Just do `test_titanic.sum()` & `test_titanic_age.sum()` and you will the difference.

You can do `test_titanic_age.get_group(22)` to get all the passengers of age 22.